# Connecting to MongoDB duration

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to connect to my MongoDB database with Java. For this I use the Mongo drivers and this line of code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(ADDRESS, PORT);
```

But only this line of code takes about 500ms. I think this should be much faster, shouldn't it? I have tried it on Windows and Linux. Both are this slow. And I've looked it up a bit but i haven't found anything.

Thank you!

Comment: are you planning to create new MongoClient for each call?

Comment: @RahulKumar Well, at the moment I do this, yes. But I am new to MongoDB. So, should I use it static?

Comment: Well, static is one way and I won't recommend it but yeah you should create the client once and use it thereafter whenever you had to use it. maybe you can check singleton pattern.

Comment: You can instantiate it once and reuse it, MongoClient is a heavyweight object. Generally speaking you can use a static variable if it is a simple application (as I think it is your case), or you might want to manage it using some IoC container (Spring, etc).

Comment: @Euclides okay, thank you. I have never heard of these IoC container. I have just searched it up. They look if one of the MongoClient is "in use" and then creates a new if this is the case. Am I right?

Comment: @user6586661no,  by default when you create an instance of MongoClient  you got a pool of 100 connections (as maximum),  that might be enough for a simple application; you do not need a new instance of MongoClient to create/read/update/delete documents.